# How to disable the responsive functionality on bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Without making too many changes, what is the best way to do this?

The website has 100's of files, I don't want to change them all. Is there a quick way?

Comment: Please explain the reason you want this question closed. It would help me ask better questions.

Comment: @Christoph Funny how you could say that for every question. I've seen that link already.

Comment: You could search in all the css sheets for `@media` and delete/comment all classes properites inside these `@media`brakects (`{}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap customize tab http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
they provide option under **Media queries breakpoints** just put `Zero` in `@screen-xs` and `@screen-sm` and add width to `.container` if required `.container-fluied`

that's it!